# Get require and optional argument in bash script

Tags: bash

Sorry for my newbie question, I'm confused!

I want to make a bash script for some reasons.
I need to pass some arguments when running the script.

for example:

```
script.sh build --with-test --without-test2 --with-test3
script.sh config
script.sh config --with-test3 --without-test2
script.sh config --add this is a test
```

`build` or `config` is required and also other parameters are optional and the order of using argument is not important.

I wrote this code:

```
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    printf "build or config parameter is missing"
    exit;
fi

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"
    case $key in
        build )
            mode=1
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        config )
            mode=0
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        -wt2 | --without-test2 )
            wt2=0
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        -wt3 | --with-test3 )
            wt3=1
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        -wt0 | --with-test )
            wt0=1
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        -add | --additional )
            additional_command=$2
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        -h | --help )
            help
            shift
            shift
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Missing parameter."
            shift
            shift
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

But my code does not work properly, the script will run even without `build` and `config`, I cannot figure out how can I write my if statements

Comment: Why complex option parsing in bash? Is this an exercise in masochism?

Comment: @melpomene :)) no this is a real requirement

Comment: This might help: `help getopts`

Comment: You are only checking that at least one argument is passed. That doesn't imply that the first argument is either `build` or `config`; you need to check for that explicitly.

Comment: @Cyrus `getopts` only handles single-letter options; it won't handle regular positional arguments or long options.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, but how can I verify that the first parameter is build or config ?

Comment: `case $1 in build|config) : ;; *); printf 'Bad subcommand %s, exiting\n' "$1" >&2; exit 1 ;; esac;`

Comment: @chepner: Thanks. This might help: `man getopt`

Comment: generally optional parameters (begin with a `-` or `--`) and come before positional parameters (also `--` is used to indicate the end of options in case positional argument can start with a `-` ) if the syntax of the command is different `getopt` or `getopts` may not be useful

Comment: `getopt` handles long options, but still doesn't process ordinary arguments in any way. [`docopts`](https://github.com/docopt/docopts) might be most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The use of shift twice is a mistake.  You can confirm that config AND/OR build has been specified by checking the value of mode.  There also looks to be an issue with additional command.

Consider moving the shift statement.

I've added some debug to your program to see what the results are:

```
$ script.sh  --with-test --without-test2 --with-test3
additional_command=
mode=
wt0=1
wt2=
wt3=1
```

As you can see, the wt2 is not set, even though --without-test2 was specified.

Here's how you can fix things up a little:

- Remove the shifts in the case (except for special processing)
- Review the mode parameter to see if it is set ( test -z )

Code follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    printf "build or config parameter is missing"
    exit;
fi

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"
shift
    case $key in
        build )
            mode=1
            ;;
        config )
            mode=0
            ;;
        -wt2 | --without-test2 )
            wt2=0
            ;;
        -wt3 | --with-test3 )
            wt3=1
            ;;
        -wt0 | --with-test )
            wt0=1
            ;;
        -add | --additional )
            # Get the rest of the parameters, right?
            additional_command=$*
            shift $# # Shift to "deplete" the rest of the params
            ;;
        -h | --help )
            help
            # No need to shift if you are exiting
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Missing parameter."
            # No need to shift if you are exiting
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done

#Here's a little debug code that you can remove or just comment out with : 
#Change first line to : cat <<EOF if you want to comment out.

cat <<EOF
    additional_command=$additional_command
    mode=$mode
    wt0=$wt0
    wt2=$wt2
    wt3=$wt3
EOF

if [ -z "$mode" ] ; then
  echo "Missing config or build parameter"

fi
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark, but one problem exists yet when I change the order of parameters, the variable cannot set, for example, if I pass the `-add` before `-wt3` the `wt3` value will be `0`. command: `script.sh config -add this is a test -wt3`